# print a total line of invoicenum and total amount for a specfic peroid

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

Input parameters: `from` date and `to` date

For specified time period print all invoices. For each show

- invoicenum,
- invoice date and
- invoice amount

Print a total line: # of invoices and total amount for the period

SQL plus

```
select invoicenum, sum(invoiceamount) as "totalamount" from invoiceheader;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

Answer (score 0):

Error you got says that column(s) which aren't aggregated should be part of the `group by` clause, i.e.

```
select invoicenum, sum(invoiceamount) as "totalamount" 
from invoiceheader
group by invoicenum;          --> this is what you are missing
```

However, that won't solve your problem as there's no `WHERE` clause (which should contain the date columns).

---

As it is about SQL*Plus, here's what I think you should have done.

I don't have your tables so I'm using Scott's sample schema.

First, all `EMP` table rows sorted by `hiredate` column:

```
SQL> select empno, ename, sal, hiredate from emp order by hiredate;

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL HIREDATE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH             800 1980-12-17
      7499 ALLEN            1600 1981-02-20
      7521 WARD             1250 1981-02-22
      7566 JONES            2975 1981-04-02
      7698 BLAKE            2850 1981-05-01
      7782 CLARK            2450 1981-06-09
      7844 TURNER           1500 1981-09-08
      7654 MARTIN           1250 1981-09-28
      7839 KING             5000 1981-11-17
      7900 JAMES             950 1981-12-03
      7902 FORD             3000 1981-12-03
      7934 MILLER           1300 1982-01-23
      7788 SCOTT            3000 1982-12-09
      7876 ADAMS            1100 1983-01-12

14 rows selected.
```

This is a simple query which utilizes the where clause (but it still won't display what you're looking for):

```
SQL> select empno, ename, sal, hiredate from emp
  2  where hiredate between date '1981-04-01' and date '1981-12-31'
  3  order by hiredate;

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL HIREDATE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7566 JONES            2975 1981-04-02
      7698 BLAKE            2850 1981-05-01
      7782 CLARK            2450 1981-06-09
      7844 TURNER           1500 1981-09-08
      7654 MARTIN           1250 1981-09-28
      7839 KING             5000 1981-11-17
      7902 FORD             3000 1981-12-03
      7900 JAMES             950 1981-12-03

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

But, if you use SQL*Plus reporting settings, you might get the result:

```
SQL> select empno, ename, sal, hiredate from emp
  2  where hiredate between date '1981-04-01' and date '1981-12-31'
  3  order by hiredate;

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL HIREDATE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7566 JONES            2975 1981-04-02
      7698 BLAKE            2850 1981-05-01
      7782 CLARK            2450 1981-06-09
      7844 TURNER           1500 1981-09-08
      7654 MARTIN           1250 1981-09-28
      7839 KING             5000 1981-11-17
      7902 FORD             3000 1981-12-03
      7900 JAMES             950 1981-12-03
----------            ----------
         8
                           19975

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

Try to apply what you've just seen to your case (homework?). Also, explore other ways of [Formatting SQL*Plus Reports](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#SQPUG016).